# filename for class files: file.class.php or file.php?

Tags: php, oop, naming-conventions

i have seen a lot of coders choosing this filename convention:

file.class.php.

is this a standard of naming class files?

just curious. so i know if i should follow it for all class files in the future.

thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no standard per se for naming class files, however `file.class.php` sends the message that it contains class files, opposed to `file.php` which may give the impression of a regular file.

My suggestion is to use one convention and be consistent with it.

#### Update:

A good point to note, as AJ, had stated, the `*.php` file extension is preferred over `*.inc` file extensions. Reason being that `*.inc` files are displayed on the client's browser as plain text and if you were to store any configuration files or private information (*especially in relation to your database, yikes*) it could potentially be accessed by anyone.

Comment: It might be worth noting the significance of using the *.php extension - some groups use *.inc or other extensions which is unwise. Otherwise I fully agree.

Comment: @AJ, I had added an update, if you know anything else that would be useful to add, do not hesitate.

Answer (score 7):

Actually this method of naming files came from developers who combines both procedural & OOPs in a same built. To differentiate procedural files and class files they did this. There is no standard convention. But I will suggest you to use **filename.php** and name the class as same as file name, just as Java convention. Keep only one class definition in a file.

@Derk: It can also be like this, there is no benefit of adding **class.** in file name ;)

```
 function __autoload ($class) {

      require_once $class . '.php';

  }

  $pizza = new pizza ();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this topic is over 10 years old, however, in my Delphi days, we named all class names starting with a T (e.g. TFiles). I am using the same technique for Php, THtml.php for the THtml class, etc. I also have one class per file.

Answer (score -1):

More common is to capitalise class files.

so class Blah would be saved as Blah.php

Comment: I don't think this is common at all....
.class.php file extension are the accepted norm

Comment: Thats a terrible advice. Introducing case-sensitivity to file system is a way to get shot in the log: autoloader (on UNIX based systems) will need to try multiple file name combinations.